# issue with mysql database while making enrty through php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make multiple tables in MySQL through PHP. The first table is master table in which names of sub-tables is recorded, linked with their respective sub-tables and the table name is also defined in the PHP code so there is no problem in entering data into that table.

The problem comes from the second tables. I will show u the code.

The first page, to make entry into master table:

```
<form action="add.php" align="center" method="GET">
<b><br><br><br>Enter the field: </b>
<input type="text" name="name1" size="30"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" size="25" value="ok"/>
```

My second page, add.php, to make entry into master table and creating a new table:

```
<?php
$area=$_GET["name1"];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO main (item_id) values('$area')"); 
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $area (item VARCHAR(30), budget INT, priority INT)"); 
print ("<h3>Now enter the details of<b> $area</h3>");
?>
<form action="field.php" method="POST">
<b> enter the field:- </b> <input type="text" name="name" size="30"/>
<b> Amount </b> <input type="integer" name="value1" size="10"/>
<b> priority </b> <input type="integer" name="value" size="10"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" size="25" value="submit"/>
```

Now third page, field.php, here error shows up. The value of `$area` (which is coming from first page) in second page goes of as i click submit button in second page:

```
<?php
$feild=$_GET["name"];
$amount=$_GET["value1"];
$priority=$_GET["value"];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $area (item, budget, priority) values('$feild',
            '$amount','$priority')");
print ("<h3>Now enter the details of<b> $area</h3>");
?>
<form action="<?php print $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
<b> enter the feild:- </b> <input type="text" name="name" size="30"/>
<b> Amount </b> <input type="integer" name="value1" size="10"/>
<b> priority </b> <input type="integer" name="value" size="10"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" size="25" value="submit"/>
```

and in the third page as I click the submit button page reloads and all the previous data vanishes which comes from the back pages.

Please let me know the fault. How I can solve this problem please help me out.

Comment: depreciated mysql* and opens to sql injection attack

Comment: You should be using the mysqli interface with prepared statements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @user1257931 :- not helping out

Comment: php variables do not pass from page to page. You need to do it manually. for eg. you could add `$area` as a hidden input in your `add.php` form -> `<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="<?php $area; ?>" />`. Then you can get the value again in `field.php` -> `$area=$_POST["name1"];`. just be aware that you are wide open to sqj injection, and allowing users to add tables, etc., can be risky.

Comment: @Sean :- its not working, may be i would be writing wrong codes. kindly please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

from Sean's answer

you can use following

```
<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="<?php echo $area; ?>" />
```